# How can I load SWT views only when they are scrolled to on the screen?

Tags: java, optimization, swt

I'm making a simple Gantt chart widget. It's basically just a Composite with a custom layout. The layout arranges all the children controls vertically to take up 100% of the parent Composite's width, like this:

[image: GanttLayout]

Here is the code that arranges the child controls this way:

```
public class GanttLayout extends Layout {

    int defaultWidth = 200;
    int width;
    int itemHeight;

    public GanttLayout(int x, int y) {
        width = x;
        itemHeight = y;

    }

    @Override
    protected Point computeSize(Composite composite, int wHint, int hHint, boolean changed) {
         int height = itemHeight * composite.getChildren().length;
         Point size = new Point(width == SWT.DEFAULT? defaultWidth: width, height + 2);
         return size;
    }

    @Override
    protected void layout(Composite composite, boolean changed) {
        int i = 0;
        for(Control control : composite.getChildren()) {
            control.setBounds(0, i * itemHeight, width == SWT.DEFAULT? composite.getSize().x: width, itemHeight);
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that when hundreds of these children controls are added, it takes a very long time for them to show up, and then it takes a very long time dispose of all the controls when they need to be disposed. Is there a way to make this more efficient? Perhaps there's a way to display the controls only when the user scrolls to them, kind of like a virtual table?

[Here is the full code](https://github.com/dublinus/GanttWidget).

Comment: The Eclipse Nebula project has a beta [Gantt widget](https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/ganttchart/ganttchart.php) which may do what you want. There is also Eclipse [nattable](http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/features.php)

Comment: I've seen a lot of these Gantt widgets (including the one you linked), but they simply don't meet my requirements. This one for example is just way too complicated and hard-to-read compared to what I need. That's the only reason I decided to create my own.